# Firebase Error: function terminated. Recommended action: inspect logs for termination reason

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I tried updating some cloud functions to Firebase that were working earlier but I'm getting odd errors. These are the errors I get for each of my functions in my main `index.js` file.

```
Deployment error.
Function failed on loading user code. This is likely due to a bug in the user code. Error message: Error: please examine your function logs to see the error cause: https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/monitoring/logging#viewing_logs. Additional troubleshooting documentation can be found at https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/troubleshooting#logging. Please visit https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/troubleshooting for in-depth troubleshooting documentation.
```

When I look at my logs I see these errors.

```
Error: function terminated. Recommended action: inspect logs for termination reason. Additional troubleshooting documentation can be found at https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/troubleshooting#logging Function cannot be initialized.
```

The documentation at the next suggested resource is very generic. How do I do additional logging to find the problem? I can run my code locally fine so I'm not sure why it won't deploy to Firebase.

I believe the problem may be from requiring a JSON file as a module. This works fine locally but does Firebase support this feature?

```
const config = require('./config.json');
```

Comment: Please include the logs as indicated in the error you included. https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/writing-and-viewing-logs#viewing_logs

Comment: Those are the logs I included.

Comment: The required module looks okay based on https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/handle-dependencies#loading_nodejs_modules

Comment: Is there any other log before that one?

Comment: I turned out to be because I was including the JSON file. I could not figure out how to resolve it so I ended up just putting my constants back in my JS files.

Answer (score 13):

sorry for my English, I speak Spanish but I'm going to try my best so you can understand me.

I'm not an expert in NodeJS but I had the same error, my problem was that I add the dependencies in *"devDependencies"* but they have to go on *"dependencies"* then we go into the project "functions" (in case of firebase) and execute in your console the next command `npm i` and next `npm ci` after we do all of this we make the deploy normally.

You can see the complete log: execute with the next command in your console `firebase functions:log --only nameYourFunction`
and search the next sentence *"Detailed stack trace: Error: Cannot find module"*
Then it will tell you which is the module that has the conflict and the log contain more information.

References:

https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/commands/npm-ci

https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/16866

Comment: Thank you. This worked for me to figure out which module was missing. I installed a module in the parent folder instead of my functions folder.

Comment: Exactly! This mistake are the most frequent.