# "Warning, FIREBASE_CONFIG and GCLOUD PROJECT environment variables are missing. Initializing firebase-admin will fail"

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions, mqtt

I have a google cloud function That will send data from iot machine to Firebase Realtime database using MQTT broker. I was running this same code on virtual machine(VM) in gcp everything was working fine i was getting data in Realtime database. i also tried this code in my local system every thing is working fine. But when i tried to run the same code on cloud function I was getting some error i have fixed some of them but i was not able to fix this error `Function cannot be initialized. Error: function terminated. Recommended action: inspect logs for termination reason. Additional troubleshooting documentation can be found at https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/troubleshooting#logging` i am adding code and some images below for better understanding.

"In this image i have shown the content or thr files which is present in cloud function"

[image]

"In this image i have shown the .json file this json file is Private key file which i have generated in json" and give the same file name in ServiceAcoount `const serviceAccount = require("./****-***-firebase-adminsdk-*****-******ca66.json");` and .runtimeconfig.json also contain private key file.

[image]

"I have not added anything in variable"

[image]

and this my code file

```js
const Admin = require("firebase-admin");
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const mqtt = require('mqtt');
const clientId = 'mqtt_googleserver_rtdb_main'
const topic = '#'

const serviceAccount = require("./****-*****-firebase-adminsdk-*****-******ca66.json");

Admin.initializeApp({
  credential: Admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
  databaseURL: "https://**********.firebaseio.com/"
});
exports.rtdb_main = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
var client = mqtt.connect('mqtt://**.***.***.***:****',{
    clientId,
    clean: true,
    connectTimeout: 4000,
    username: '******',
    password: '*********',
    reconnectPeriod: 1000,
})
const db = Admin.database();
 
 //client.addListener or client.on is used to listen to the event 'connect' below 
  client.addListener('connect',function(){
    console.log('Connected')
    client.subscribe([topic],{qos:1})
    console.log(`Subscribe to topic '${topic}'`)
})
client.on('message', (topic, payload) => {
    console.log('Received Message:', topic, payload.toString())
    if(payload.toString() !== "" && topic !== ""){
    var ref = db.ref("All_machines")
    var childref = ref.child(topic.toString())
   childref.set(payload.toString())
   //Use the code below to isolate any data from All Machines
   const topicDetails = topic.split("/")
   const catagory = topicDetails[0]
   const machineId = topicDetails[1]
   const machineParameter = topicDetails[2]
   
   if (machineParameter === "BoardID")
   {
   var ref = db.ref(machineParameter)
   ref.set(machineId)
   }
   }
  }) 
});
```

This is my package.json

```json
{
  "name": "sample-http",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "Cloud Function for Realtime Database",
   "scripts": {
    "serve": "firebase emulators:start --only functions",
      "shell": "firebase functions:shell",
      "start": "npm run shell",
      "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
      "logs": "firebase functions:log"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "16"
  },
  "main": "index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "firebase-admin": "^11.4.1",
    "firebase-functions": "^3.14.1",
    "mqtt": "^4.3.7",
    "node-schedule": "^2.1.0"
  },

  "devDependencies": {
    "firebase-functions-test": "^0.2.0"
  },
  "private": true
 
}
```

Comment: Have you gone through the suggestions in these similar search cases ["Warning, FIREBASE_CONFIG and GCLOUD PROJECT environment variables are missing. Initializing firebase-admin will fail"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22Warning%2C+FIREBASE_CONFIG+and+GCLOUD+PROJECT+environment+variables+are+missing&rlz=1CAOLRV_enIN990&oq=%22Warning%2C+FIREBASE_CONFIG+and+GCLOUD+PROJECT+environment+variables+are+missing&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i59l2j0i22i30j69i60l3.466j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Comment: Yes I have gone through this

Comment: I think I am doing something wrong where I am initialising Service account. I have added the private key file in the same folder you can see in the 1st image. @SathiAiswarya

Comment: Have a look  at this [document](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/troubleshooting#function_terminated) also so [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65227667/firebase-error-function-terminated-recommended-action-inspect-logs-for-termin) & github [link](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-functions/issues/987)